# Android: ExpandableListAdapter IndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception, expandablelistadapter

I have a bug in my code where if your switching between tabs really fast or if your swiping up and down on the screen really fast, I get this IndexOutOfBoundsException, and I've noticed other people get this in Android also, so I looked it up but haven't seen the error with mine, and was wondering if anyone could help me? Thank you.

```
public abstract class ExListAdapter<T> extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

protected FragmentActivity _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; 
private Map<String, List<T>> _listDataChild; 

public ExListAdapter(FragmentActivity context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             Map<String, List<T>> listDataChild) {
    _context = context;
    _listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    _listDataChild = listDataChild;
}



@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

    return _listDataChild.get(_listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);

}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

    if (_listDataChild.isEmpty() || _listDataHeader.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        String header = _listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
        List<T> numChildren = _listDataChild.get(header);
        return numChildren != null ? numChildren.size() : 0;
    }


}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return _listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {

   return _listDataHeader.size();

}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition){
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
}
}
```

Logcat:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at com.private.private.ExListAdapter.getGroup(ExListAdapter.java:72)
        at com.private.private.ExListAdapter.getGroupView(ExListAdapter.java:89)
        at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:446)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1616)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2087)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:343)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1983)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1740)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You did not and are not going to tell which line caused that?

Comment: Sorry this line "return _listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);" from the method getGroup is line 72 and "String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);" is line 89

Comment: It's simply because your trying to access an index in your list that doesn't exist (is out of bounds.) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html Debug your code to get a clearer view of what's going wrong.

Comment: It can only happen when _listDataHeader is empty. Which would be strange if you could scroll.

Comment: Looks like a multi-threading issue between your thread and UI thread. Android is full of such (flawed) behaviors at GUI level. Make sure the array has elements before allowing scrolling.